# bigloo scheme "make test" fails for pthreads

Tags: makefile, pthreads, scheme, bigloo

I am trying to build from the bigloo scheme's latest source 3.8a on a Linux Mint 12 (lisa), which is Ubuntu 11 (Oneric) derivative:

Here is my "configure":

```
./configure --enable-pthread --enable-fthread --enable-ssl --enable-sqlite --enable-web --enable-multimedia --enable-mail --enable-calendar --enable-pkgcomp --enable-pkglib --enable-gstreamer --enable-text --enable-srfi1 --enable-srfi27 --enable-crypto --enable-openpgp --enable-phone --enable-alsa --enable-mpg123 --enable-csv --jvm=yes


** Configuration summary **

Release features:
  release number.............. 3.8a
  supported backends.......... native:yes JVM:yes
  default backend............. native
  additional APIs............. pthread fthread sqlite web multimedia mail calendar pkgcomp pkglib text srfi1 srfi27 packrat crypto openpgp phone mpg123 csv
  native threads support...... yes
  openssl support............. no
  sqlite support.............. sqltiny + sqlite
  dynamic libraries support... yes

Bee configuration:
  bee support................. partial
  emacs....................... emacs
  emacs brand................. emacs23

Implementation details:
  tuning...................... standard 
  cc.......................... gcc
  gc.......................... custom (bigloogc-3.8a, v731)
  Java version................ 1.3
  bignum support.............. gmp (5.0.1)

Directories where Bigloo will be installed:
  binaries.................... /usr/local/bin
  libraries................... /usr/local/lib
  files directory............. bigloo/3.8a
  standard zip................ /usr/local/lib/bigloo/3.8a
  standard dll................ /usr/local/lib/bigloo/3.8a
  manual pages................ /usr/local/man/man1
  info documentation.......... /usr/local/info
  lisp files.................. 
  temporary build dir......... /tmp
```

The "make" succeeds; however "make test" fails for pthread

```
*** pthread ********** 
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/liew/Downloads/bigloo3.8a/api/pthread/recette'
/home/liew/Downloads/bigloo3.8a/bin/bigloo -c  -call/cc  -O3 -fcfa-arithmetic -q recette.scm -o recette.o
/home/liew/Downloads/bigloo3.8a/bin/bigloo  -O3 -fcfa-arithmetic -q recette.o -o recette
/usr/bin/ld: recette: hidden symbol `pthread_atfork' in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a(pthread_atfork.oS) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [recette] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/liew/Downloads/bigloo3.8a/api/pthread/recette'
make[1]: *** [c-test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/liew/Downloads/bigloo3.8a'
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

According to this [excellent post](http://ryanarn.blogspot.com/) about this pthread issue, we need to rearrange the command line parameters while linking pthread library. However, I was unable to find the required Makefile code - probably because it relies on the Makefile default that links the library in a certain way.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably fixed in newer versions of bigloo.